# python: replacing negative values in array read from file

Tags: python, arrays, replace, where-clause

I'm populating an array, reading data from file:

**Input:**

```
2
4
-8
5
-2
```

**Code:**

```
f = [ i.strip() for i in open('file.txt', 'r') ]
a = []

for line in f:
   line = line.split()
   a.append(float(line[0]))
```

that produces the vector `a=[2,4,-8,5,-2]`. Now I want to replace all negative values with their values +10, in order to obtain a vector `b=[2,4,2,5,8]`. Without using a loop or a `for` cycle, how can I do that? I tried both using the `np.where()` function and the `a[a<0]`, but they don't produce any result (they just work if I create a `np.array[2,4,-8,5,-2]` ex novo...). Thank you in advance.

Comment: Why not do it in your `i.strip() for... ` loop?

Comment: After all there'll be a loop, no matter what function you choose to use.

Comment: What would -11 become? -1 or add 10 again to get +9?

Answer (score 4):

one way not using numpy

`a = list(map(lambda x:x+10 if x < 0 else x, a))`

Comment: Nice to see a functional answer in here. The more Pythonic way to write this notation would be
`a = [x+10 if x < 0 else x for x in a]`

Answer (score 2):

You could make `a` a numpy array:

```
a = np.array(a)
```

and then simply do:

```
a[a<0] += 10
```

Comment: IN my opinion Numpy is wayyyy overkill unless you're reading a ton of values and doing performance-critical computations on them. There's a simple way of binary-filtering values in python, that's with an `if-else` expression.

Comment: @machineyearning But OP explicitely said "Without using a loop or a for cycle" ... One could argue though if list comprehension is actually a for loop.

Comment: In that case I'd also question whether numpy array iteration uses some kind of a loop. I had read OP as meaning he would like a way to do it with a single expression, rather than a syntax block. I digress though, OP did mention numpy, so it could actually be the case that this is a large and performance-critical set of numbers to crunch. In that case it's up to OP to choose the right answer that fits his/her needs.

Answer (score 2):

It can be done with list comprehension without using NumPy. Assuming you have list of numbers a:

```
>>> a = [2, 4, -8, 5, -2]
>>> [number if number >= 0 else number + 10 for number in a]
[2, 4, 2, 5, 8]
```

Answer (score 1):

If you allow the use of numpy:

```
import numpy as np

f = [ i.strip() for i in open('C:/Users/simon/Desktop/file.txt', 'r') ]
a = []

for line in f:
   line = line.split()
   a.append(float(line[0]))

a = np.array(a)

print a

a[a<0] = a[a<0] + 10

print a
```

That will give you:

```
[ 2.  4. -8.  5. -2.]
[ 2.  4.  2.  5.  8.]
```